# How the computer system identify the application is 32-bit or 64-bit

Tags: 32-bit

As we know, the 64-bit system (like windows) can run both 32-bit applications or 64-bit applications. Under Windows 64-bit, 32-bit applications run on top of an emulation of a 32-bit operating system that is called Windows 32-bit on Windows 64-bit, or WOW64 for short.

---

Here, I want to know, how can the 64-bit system knows the application is 32-bit or 64-bit?  So, the windows 64-bit or WOW64 can be chose to run the application correctly.

Answer (score 1):

By examining `Machine` field of the [COFF header](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/X86_Disassembly/Windows_Executable_Files#COFF_Header).